# Does one mourn during the days following Shavuot?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mourning-aveilus, shavuos, korban

We say the four verses starting "Yehi Shem" (instead of Tachanun) after Shavuot because of the bringing of the Korbanot. Does this have any impact on mourning after Shavuot?

Comment: Are you referring to mourning for recently deceased relatives?

Comment: Yes... sitting Shiva @DoubleAA

Comment: You should clarify that in the question by [edit]ing.

Comment: Just to second @DoubleAA, as the title is worded at the moment it looks as though you're asking whether or not somebody *should* mourn (which I assumed was related to the *behab* fasts after Pesach and Sukkot), not whether or not they can. I think the body of the question is fine though, so long as the title is a bit clearer.

Comment: Are you asking about the case where the person being mourned died *before* Shavuot* or *after* Shavuot?

Answer (score -1):

This does not seem to be the ashkenaz minhag to say these verses. Isru chag is kept outside Israel on Friday meaning basically eating a special meal. If anything Isru chag is more important on shvuous since there is no chol hamoed. Also a yahrzeit does not have to fast.
In Israel six days after shvuous they dont say tachnun because in keeping with pesach and succos one could still bring the yom tov offerings. Outside Israel one doesnt say tachnun for five days. I am not sure if also one doesnt say on the sixth day after shvuous outside Israel or if a yahrzeit does not have to fast on these extra days after isru chag.

Comment: Some sources would greatly improve your answer (as would noting which of these rules are universal or community specific).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which asks about mourning.